# Match and split of an Array of String PHP

Tags: php, arrays, split, match

I'm having troubles finding the code for this:

I have this array:

```
$filtros['code']  = 1 
$filtros['name'] = 'John'
$filtros['formacion_c_1'] = 2
$filtros['formacion_c_2'] = 1
$filtros['formacion_c_3'] = 2
```

And I need to catch the number of each "formacion_c_{number}" and his value

```
echo "The Formation number {number} has the value $filtros[formacion_c_{number}]";
```

the result that I need is something like :

```
The Formation number 1 has the value 2.
The Formation number 2 has the value 1.
The Formation number 3 has the value 2.
```

surely the solution is with some preg_split or preg_match, but I can't handle this

Comment: Do you get this array from someone or do you define it yourself? If the later, why not use a 2D array?

Comment: I'm getting this array from a Form

Comment: @grteibo: Forms can send you arrays.  `<input name="formacion_c[]" />`.  Then `$_POST['formacion_c']` will be an array.

Comment: yes, but this is not possible in Zend_Form_Elements, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($filtros as $key=>$val){
    if(preg_match('/^formacion_c_(\d)+$/', $key, $match) === 1){
        echo "The Formation number {$match[1]} has the value $val";
    }
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/iscQ7

Comment: This code is ok! just is "c_formacion_" instead of "formacion_c_" thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use multidimensional arrays for this?

Instead of:

```
filtros['formacion_c_1'] = 2
filtros['formacion_c_2'] = 1
filtros['formacion_c_3'] = 2
```

Why not:

```
filtros['formacion_c']['1'] = 2
filtros['formacion_c']['2'] = 1
filtros['formacion_c']['3'] = 2
```

[edit]
I noticed in the comments you said you get this array from a form. You can have multidimensional arrays in HTML forms.
[/edit]

If you can't change the code I guess you could loop through each element and compare the key:

```
$keyStart = 'formacion_c_';
foreach($filtros as $key => $value) {
     if(strstr($key, $keyStart)) {
          $id = str_replace($keyStart, '', $key);
     }
}
```

Comment: uhm i think I cant do multidimensional arrays in Zend_forms_elements, im getting this Formacion_c_1, formacion_c_2 from differents Zend_Form_Element_Select